# Dynamic DNS updater

Tags: dyndns

I am searching for some tool like a DynDNS updater - but I am looking for a free one.
The tool should report the IP change of the server, so I can access it always. Is there any free tool/service which support this ? 
Thank you.

Comment: Why is your server changing IP?  It shouldn't.  If you're talking about being able to access your home PC from anywhere, then this belongs on SuperUser.com

Answer (score 3):

Check your router as some routers have this function build in..

Answer (score 2):

DynDNS has a free updated client, or you can update it from many consumer routers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [afraid.org](http://freedns.afraid.org/) and it has many free clients to update the IP and if you have a [dd-wrt](http://www.dd-wrt.com/dd-wrtv3/index.php) it has support for it.

Comment: +1 for afraid.org. You can choose hundreds of domains to use or even your owh (all for free)..

Answer (score 1):

yey, no-ip.org ... it´s free (just subdomains like hello123.no-ip.org).
u can intall it form debian using apt-get install no-ip.
U first must register at www.no-ip.org

Regards!

Comment: I use a free no-ip subdomain and use a $3/month shared hosting with my own domain name to check if my server is online, and redirect appropriately. Really important things have a copy on my shared hosting as well.

Answer (score 1):

EveryDNS used to have this, but I switched to DynDNS because I found out my router has support for DynDNS.